# Развёртывание на VDS Tomcat 8 JSP-сайта через IDEA по FTP

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, tomcat, vds

Мною был поднят VDS сервер на amazonaws.com, на базе Win Server 2016 на нём FTP jdk1.8.0_131 и apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22 запущен как сервис
после некоторых танцев с бубном получилось таки подружить Intellij idea + Tomcat Server Remote и настроить чтобы он туда делал Deployment по FTP

вопрос, который возникает - что такое "path from root" и "mapped as". На оффсайте jetbrains описано крайне скудно по сему установил в качестве значений папку

```
\tomcat\webapps
```

собственно сам процесс передачи файлов проходит успешно, они появляются на сервере но на стороне Intellij idea вылетает ошибка

```
[2017-07-03 08:31:50,761] Artifact TestWeb2:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
[2017-07-03 08:31:54,494] Artifact TestWeb2:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Connected to server
[2017-07-03 08:32:08,627] Artifact TestWeb2:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

на стороне сервера имеем вот такой лог

```
03-Jul-2017 16:57:11.834 INFO [localhost-startStop-11] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT]
03-Jul-2017 16:57:11.887 INFO [localhost-startStop-11] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [53] ms
03-Jul-2017 16:58:01.902 INFO [localhost-startStop-12] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT]
03-Jul-2017 16:58:01.954 INFO [localhost-startStop-12] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [52] ms
03-Jul-2017 16:58:07.816 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3045)-178.126.244.56] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method createStandardContext
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Если запускать на локальном сервере то всё прекрасно стартует, но хочется именно чтобы сразу на удалённом всё это происходило. Посоветуйте в какую сторону можно смотреть

Comment: Можете подробнее описать, что вы делали для настройки деплоя? Я хотел то же самое сделать, но стало лень "танцевать с бубном" и настраивать JMX и прочее.

Comment: Это публичный IP *178.126.244.56* ? посмотрите настройки в NACL, Security Group чтобы нужные вам порты были открыты.  ПС. зачем танцы с бубном если можно деплоить сразу в томкат через maven/gradle?

Comment: ну там просто нужно прописать в качестве параметров -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=твой_внешний_адресс

Comment: все порты открыты по JMX я подключаюсь, всё на сервер заливается но запустится не может